# How would I make be able to tell when there is an error in my Python program, so I could create my own custom error message

Tags: python, variables, gtk, glade

I am writing a program with `GTK` where you have to insert text in a settings menu. If the settings are imputed wrong, the terminal will display an error message. It does not matter what the error message is, I just want  to be able to create my own error message telling the user to correct the problem, and how to correct the problem.

I thought something like this would work:

```
if OSError == true:
    print "Custom Error Message"
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You should use `try` -- `except` block for that. Just catch the exception and the rise your own, example:

```
class MyOwnException(Exception): pass

try:
    x = 4 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    raise MyOwnException("You cannot divide a number by 0!!")
```

**Note that raising your own exception will need you handle it, otherwise if no `except` block is found in the context, the program will stop and complain about such exception.** So, if you only want to show a message you can:

```
try:
    x = 4 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("You cannot divide a number by 0!!")
```

Comment: "...raising your exception will stop the programm execution..." - I don't think this is precise enough. Rather it will pass the exception up through the calling contexts until it reaches the end of the program (if nothing else catches it).

Comment: @SimonFeltman Read the answer carefully, and see the note I left: `Note that raising your exception will stop the programm execution as well`. And see the second snippet of code. Perhaps I have to write the note in bold font.

Comment: I, see, you´re right I misunderstood your previuos comment.

Comment: Stopping program execution sounds a bit abrupt (as in C's exit()), it raises an exception up through the calling contexts which may or may not result in the program stopping.

Answer (score -1):

Use `raise` and provide your own message when you initialize an error:

```
if OSError:
    raise Exception("Your custom error message")
```

Comment: What are you expecting `if OSError` to do?

Comment: I don't know, but i didn't type that.

Comment: I expected OSError to be some previously caught exception, but you're right, that's not an intelligent assumption to make.